# Conflict between babel and university style sheet

Tags: babel, linguistics, cyrillic

I am a Linguistics PhD student at U.Florida, writing my dissertation. The LaTeX class from our editorial office conflicts with `babel` (among other packages). Is there a way to override the style sheet temporarily in order to use `babel`?

The template can be downloaded from http://helpdesk.ufl.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/latex_spring_2011.zip.

The template is actually a number of different .tex files. When I have `\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}` in the `packages.tex` file, Russian glyphs appear in the PDF, but in the Table of Contents (with very specific requirements from the university editorial office) 'REFERENCES' (good) reverts to 'Bibliography' (not good). As soon as I comment out `\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}`, I get 'REFERENCES' back (good), but I lose my Russian glyphs.

I assume the problem is with the university's style sheet. Any thoughts on how to make it work?

```
\documentclass[12pt,dvipdfm,final,CPage]{ufthesis}  
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newcommand{\sfcyrillic}{PTSans-TLF}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\Russian}
{\selectfont}
{\fontfamily{\sfcyrillic}\selectfont}
\xshowcmd\Russian
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\sfcyrillic}{PTSans-TLF}\normalfont
English text.\\
Russian text: \\
\textcyrillic{у меня есть жиншина. я очень харашо.}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Didn't I already answer the question about `gb4e`? [Conflict between gb4e and my university style sheet](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106519). Your question isn't very clear since what you write in the question doesn't match what your test document does. And your test document doesn't compile as is.

Comment: @AlanMunn, you're right, this is related to the earlier question. Based on your help, I was able to render Cyrillics glyphs. What I didn't notice until recently is that by using `babel`, it alters some part of the `ufthesis` document class provided by UF. Specifically, it takes what is supposed to be 'REFERENCES' and renders it 'Bibliography'. I see your point about the test data not doing what it's supposed to do. The UF template is so complicated, I don't know how to consolidate all the code from multiple files into a single test document, especially the Table of Contents and Bib/Ref part.

Comment: Try the following: `\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}}` after loading `babel`.

Comment: @AlanMunn, the code you suggested worked perfectly. For future UF students dealing with the same issue, below is the code to fix five significant changes that are unacceptable to the UF editorial office. After
`\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}`, add
`\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}}`
`\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand\abstractname{ABSTRACT}}`
`\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}}`
`\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}}`
`\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand\contentsname{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the `babel` package creates hooks for document parts so that they can be represented in different languages, if you load `babel` you need to tell it to add the correctly formatted names to its hooks.  The general command for doing this is

```
\addto\captions<language>{<code>}
```

So in your case, since you need all the names to be uppercase and with particular names, you need to add commands like the following for each of the part names:

```
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}}
```

etc.